# How do you make an automatic "slideshow" of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm probably describing this really strangely, but I was wondering how I'd go about making a script that would show text and then the text would fade and new text would show up.

For example, I'd have a line of text saying "I like [object]" and then the object would fade in, show "apples", fade out, fade in, show "cats", etc.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to research [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). It's an amazing JavaScript library with functions that do exactly what you're looking to do.

Specifically,

[fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/),
[fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/),
[fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/),
[fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/)

Give the API for them a read and try them out. If you have problems post another question there's lots of people here that know a lot about JQuery.